# How to check that a type hint is compatible with Iterable in code?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I'd like to have a function `isiterable(t: type) -> bool` that will return true if the type I pass is an iterable and is false otherwise.

```
assert isiterable(int) == False
assert isiterable(str) == False
assert isiterable(Iterable[int]) == True
```

I've been using type hints for a while to decorate functions. However, I'm now working on some code that needs to by type-hint aware. I know very little about this. I'm targeting python 3.7, if that makes a difference. So there may be an obvious answer to this.

I can construct this by brute force - checking to see if the name of the type class is `_GenericAlias`, and then checking that `_name` is `Iterator` - but that does not feel robust or future proof for many reasons!

Edit: My question is not clearly written it would seem. I think what I'm after is called *type introspection*. I've got an answer below that works but is almost certainly not pythonic in the least. I'm trying to support, if it makes any difference, 3.7 and 3.8 - tho supporting 3.6 would be nice.

Comment: if it has `__iter__` or `__getitem__`, then it's a iterable

Comment: Maybe I'm starting from the wrong place and getting confused about what `type` means in python - I need to check a type-hint, not the object itself. So I need to behave like `mypy` or `pyright`.

Comment: If you look here and scroll down a bit, there is an `from typing import Iterator`, that is probably what you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Yes, the generic type (which becomes a `Protocol` in version 3.8). I think what I need is called "type introspection"?

Answer (score 0):

check the doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=iterable#collections.abc.Iterable

if you wrote something like:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def isiterable(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, Iterable)
```

it will only check if it's a subclass of `Iterable` or if it has `__iter__` method. it's not accurate.

any object with `__iter__` or `__getitem__` is a iterable. so you may use these two methods to write an Iterable

```py
# with __iter__ and __next__
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.x:
            self.n += 1
            return 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration

# with __setitem__ and __getitem__
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = [None] * x

    def __setitem__(self, index, data):
        self.x[index] = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index]
```

> The only reliable way to determine whether an object is iterable is to call iter(obj)

```py
def isiterable(obj):
    try:
        print(iter(obj))
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True


print(isiterable(Foo(1)))
print(isiterable(Bar(1)))

# <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f3fe2703bb0>
# True
# iterator object at 0x7f3fe269f400>
# True
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely works to check an object. I need to check a type-hint, however. So I need to check that "Iterable[str]" is and "str" is not. At some level, I need to behave like a static type checker (pyright and mypy).

Comment: @Gordon `from typing import Iterable`？

Comment: Sure - but if I've got `Iterable` imported, and I have `x=Iterable[int]` how do I know that `x` contains a type derived from `Iterable[T]` where `T` is a wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works - but it feels like it is depending on implementation details rather than a public API for the type system. I'll mark this an answer for now until I or someone else posts something more correct:

```py
from typing import Type
def is_iterable(t: Type) -> bool:
        if type(i_type).__name__ != '_GenericAlias':
            return False

        import collections
        if i_type.__origin__ != collections.abc.Iterable:
            return False

        return True
```

If you also wanted to know what `X` was in `Iterable[X]`, you could get that via `i_type.__args__[0]`.

Comment: Should `i_type` and `t` be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
import typing
from collections import abc

def is_iterable(type_hint: type) -> bool:
    return (hasattr(type_hint, '__origin__') 
            and type_hint.__origin__ in  {abc.Iterable, typing.Iterable})
```