# How to check a class/type is iterable (uninstantiated)

Tags: python, iterable, introspection, type-annotation

I am inspecting type hints such as `list[int]` which is a GenericAlias.

If I get the origin using `typing.get_origin(list[int])` or `list[int].__origin__` it returns the class type list, as expected: `<class 'list'>`

How can I check if the class is iterable without instantiating it, or is that the only way?
The usual `iter()` and `isinstance(object, collections.abc.Iterable)` obviously don't work as they expect the instantiated object, not the class.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63467262/5683049), but doesn't seem to work correctly in Python `3.10` (even when `i_type` variable is substituted for `t`).

Comment: You could check wether the class has the __iter__ method and the __next__ method using something like if '__iter__' in obj.__dict__ and '__next__' in obj.__dict__

Comment: @std124_lf Thanks. That seems like it could work:
`if '__iter__' in obj.__dict__ and '__next__' in obj.__dict__ or '__getitem__' in obj.__dict__:
    print('Is iterable')`.

Are there any pitfalls to this method that you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on what *you* define as **iterable**.

The [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module considers a class to implement the `Iterable` protocol once it defines the `__iter__` method. Note that you **do not need** to define the `__next__` method. This is only needed, if you want to implement an `Iterator`. (Those two often get confused.)

A slightly broader definition in accordance with the the general notion of an iterable in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) also includes classes that implement `__getitem__` (with integer indexes starting at 0 as Sequences do).

In practice this means that you have an iterable class, if and only if you can call the built-in [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) function with an instance of that class. That function merely calls the instance's `__iter__` method, if it finds one.

If that is what you consider to be iterable as well, the most reliable way to check that I can think of is the following. We first find out if one of the classes in the method resolution order implements the desired instance method:

*(Thanks @user2357112 for reminding me of checking inherited methods.)*

```py
def _implements_instance_method(cls: type, name: str) -> type | None:
    """
    Checks whether a class implements a certain instance method.

    Args:
        cls: Class to check; superclasses (except `object`) are also checked
        name: The name of the instance method that `cls` should have

    Returns:
        The earliest class in the MRO of `cls` implementing the instance
        method with the provided `name` or `None` if none of them do.
    """
    for base in cls.__mro__[:-1]:  # do not check `object`
        if name in base.__dict__ and callable(base.__dict__[name]):
            return base
    return None
```

That first check is self-explanatory; if it fails, we obviously don't have that method. But this is where it gets a little pedantic.

The second check actually does more than one thing. First off it ensures that that the `name` on our `cls` is defined as a method, i.e. callable. But it also ensures us against any descriptor shenanigans (to an extent). This is why we check `callable(cls.__dict__[name])` and not simply `callable(getattr(cls, name))`.

If someone were to (for whatever reason) have a `@classmethod` or a `@property` called `name`, that would not fly here.

Next we write our actual iterable checking function:

```py
def is_iterable_class(cls: type, strict: bool = True) -> bool:
    """
    Returns `True` only if `cls` implements the iterable protocol.

    Args:
        cls:
            The class to check for being iterable
        strict (optional):
            If `True` (default), only classes that implement (or inherit)
            the `__iter__` instance method are considered iterable;
            if `False`, classes supporting `__getitem__` subscripting
            will be considered iterable.
            -> https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable

    Returns:
        `True` if `cls` is to be considered iterable; `False` otherwise.
    """
    if not isinstance(cls, type):
        return False
    if _implements_instance_method(cls, "__iter__") is None:
        if strict:
            return False
        return _implements_instance_method(cls, "__getitem__") is not None
    return True
```

There are still a number of pitfalls here though.

A little demo:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


class MyIter(Iterable[T]):
    def __init__(self, *items: T) -> None:
        self._items = items

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(self._items)


class SubIter(MyIter[T]):
    pass


class IdxIter(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, *items: T) -> None:
        self._items = items

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> T:
        return self._items[idx]


class Foo:
    __iter__ = "bar"


class Bar:
    @classmethod
    def __iter__(cls) -> Iterator[int]:
        return iter(range(5))


class Baz:
    def __iter__(self) -> int:
        return 1


def _implements_instance_method(cls: type, name: str) -> type | None:
    """
    Checks whether a class implements a certain instance method.

    Args:
        cls: Class to check; base classes (except `object`) are also checked
        name: The name of the instance method that `cls` should have

    Returns:
        The earliest class in the MRO of `cls` implementing the instance
        method with the provided `name` or `None` if none of them do.
    """
    for base in cls.__mro__[:-1]:  # do not check `object`
        if name in base.__dict__ and callable(base.__dict__[name]):
            return base
    return None


def is_iterable_class(cls: type, strict: bool = True) -> bool:
    """
    Returns `True` only if `cls` implements the iterable protocol.

    Args:
        cls:
            The class to check for being iterable
        strict (optional):
            If `True` (default), only classes that implement (or inherit)
            the `__iter__` instance method are considered iterable;
            if `False`, classes supporting `__getitem__` subscripting
            will be considered iterable.
            -> https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable

    Returns:
        `True` if `cls` is to be considered iterable; `False` otherwise.
    """
    if not isinstance(cls, type):
        return False
    if _implements_instance_method(cls, "__iter__") is None:
        if strict:
            return False
        return _implements_instance_method(cls, "__getitem__") is not None
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(MyIter)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(SubIter)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(IdxIter)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(IdxIter, strict=False)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(Foo)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(Bar)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(Baz)=}")
    print(f"{is_iterable_class(np.ndarray)=}")
    try:
        iter(np.array(1))
    except TypeError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

The output:

```
is_iterable_class(MyIter)=True
is_iterable_class(SubIter)=True
is_iterable_class(IdxIter)=False
is_iterable_class(IdxIter, strict=False)=True
is_iterable_class(Foo)=False
is_iterable_class(Bar)=False
is_iterable_class(Baz)=True
is_iterable_class(np.ndarray)=True
TypeError('iteration over a 0-d array')
```

You should immediately notice that my function returns `True` for `Baz` even though it clearly messes up and delivers an integer instead of an `Iterator`. This is to demonstrate that the contract of the [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) protocol ends at the definition of `__iter__` and does not cover what it returns. Even though one would reasonably assume that it must return an `Iterator`, it is technically still an `Iterable` even if it doesn't.

Another great practical example of this was pointed out by *@user2357112*: The `numpy.ndarray` is certainly iterable, by contract and in practice in most situations. However, when it is a 0D-array (i.e. a scalar), the `__iter__` method raises a `TypeError` because iterating over a scalar makes little sense.

The non-`strict` version of the function is even less practical since a class could easily **and sensibly** implement `__getitem__`, but not in the way expected by `iter()`.

I see no way around those issues and even the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#id18) tells you that

> the only reliable way to determine whether an object is iterable is to call `iter(obj)`.

---

If it is *actually* the `Iterator` that you are interested in, you could of course expand the function to do the same checks done for the `__iter__` method also for the `__next__` method. But keep in mind that this will immediately exclude all the built-in collection types like `list`, `dict` etc. because they actually **don't** implement `__next__`. Again, referring to `collections.abc`, you can see that all `Collection` subtypes only inherit from `Iterable`, not from `Iterator`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `is_iterable_class` fails for classes that inherit their `__iter__` method, like `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: For a more practical case than `Baz` of not being able to tell whether something is iterable by examining the class, consider `numpy.ndarray`, from the extremely popular NumPy library. It defines `__iter__`, and most instances of `numpy.ndarray` are indeed iterable... *except* 0-dimensional arrays. For those, iteration does not make sense, and `__iter__` raises `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`.

Comment: Or, consider weak proxies from the stdlib `weakref` module. `weakref.ProxyType` and `weakref.CallableProxyType` both implement `__iter__`, but whether calling `iter` on a weak proxy will actually work depends on the object it's a proxy of.

Comment: @user2357112 Good catch about the inherited method. I'll try and edit my answer. As for your other points, those just confirm what I stated in my post, right? There is no guarantee that that you'll get an iterator, just because the `Iterable` protocol is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, the second and third comments are intended to confirm that the "`Iterable` isn't enough" issue actually arises in libraries people use.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you. I edited and expanded my answer.