# collections.abc.Iterable doesn't allows runtime structural checks according to Iterable API

Tags: python, python-typing, abc, structural-typing

[Existing Approaches to Structural Subtyping](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#existing-approaches-to-structural-subtyping)

> Abstract classes defined in `collections.abc` module are slightly more advanced since they implement a custom `__subclasshook__()` method that allows runtime structural checks without explicit registration:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

class MyIterable:
    def __iter__(self):
        return []

assert isinstance(MyIterable(), Iterable)
```

But [Python glossary: Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` method or with a `__getitem__()` method that implements Sequence semantics.

"or with a `__getitem__()`"

So I expect that this code run without any `AssertionError`:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

class MyIterable:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return []

assert isinstance(MyIterable(), Iterable)
```

But it doesn't:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert isinstance(MyIterable(), Iterable)
AssertionError
```

So why, even if an Iterable should implement `__iter__` OR `__getitem__`, `__getitem__` doesn't works if we want to check if it's an Iterable.

I also tested with `Mypy`:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

class MyIterable1:
    def __iter__(self):
        return []

class MyIterable2:
    def __getitem__(self):
        return []

def foo(bar: Iterable):
    ...

foo(MyIterable1())
foo(MyIterable2())
```

Type check result:

```
$ mypy .\scratch_443.py
test_file.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "MyIterable2"; expected "Iterable[Any]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you did cite most of the relevant passages, I would like to add a little bit of additional context and another perspective.

The problem lies (as it often does) in the definitions, of which there are two in this case.

---

### The abstract base `Iterable`

The `collections.abc.Iterable` is not flawed, it just leans on a more **narrow** definition of the term. In that definition, if a class implements the `__iter__` method, it is considered iterable; plain and simple. Mind you, this does not (and can not) impose *any* constraints on what happens inside that method or what it returns.

One of the consequences of this is that technically the method *could* return something silly, like an integer for example, even though we would reasonably *expect* the `__iter__` method to always return an [**iterator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (i.e. something implementing the `__next__` method).

Case in point:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

class Foo:
    def __iter__(self) -> int:
        return 1

assert isinstance(Foo(), Iterable)  # passes
iter(Foo())  # TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'int'
```

The error is only raised *inside* the `iter` function, as it presumably checks the existence of `__next__` in the `__dict__` of the class (!) of the provided object.

```py
class NotReallyAnIterator:
    __next__ = None

class Foo:
    def __iter__(self) -> NotReallyAnIterator:
        return NotReallyAnIterator()

it = iter(Foo())  # passes
next(it)  # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This last point is tangential, but still relevant to the discussion IMO.

---

### The loose term "iterable"

The term *"iterable"* is defined more broadly in the glossary as an object whose class corresponds to the aforementioned `Iterable` protocol *or*, as you quoted,

> with a `__getitem__()` method **that implements Sequence semantics**.

And you'll notice I highlighted that last portion of the sentence. This part is actually important to understanding the problem at hand. This is unfortunately not expanded on further in the glossary, but if we take a look at the documentation for the built-in [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), which is (as the docs tell us) the **only** reliable way of checking, if an object is iterable, we find the following clarification. It says the argument

> must be a collection object which supports the iterable protocol (the `__iter__()` method), or it must support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method **with integer arguments starting at `0`**).

This qualification is important because simply having the `__getitem__` method does **not** constitute a `Sequence`. It is a *necessary* but not sufficient requirement, as e.g. the `Mapping` protocol *also* requires the `__getitem__` method to be implemented, but neither of those two is a subclass of the other (as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)).

[`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) merely allows subscripting an instance with a `key` (i.e. using square brackets `[key]` with them) and the **sequence** protocol requires an accepted `key` to be an integer (or slice).

Why is this relevant?

Because while we can know **if** an object's class implements `__getitem__`, it is impossible to know from the outside **how** it implements it. A `Sequence` subtype should raise an error, if we were to try and call its `__getitem__` with a string for example. But how con we know that it does? Only by calling it.

And since specifically the sequence protocol (and not just *any* `__getitem__` method) is what constitutes an *"iterable"* in the absence of `__iter__` in this broader sense, there is **no way to determine**, if a class should or should not be considered iterable.

To top this all off, consider the following example:

```py
class Bar:
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> str:
        return key.upper()

it = iter(Bar())  # passes
print(next(it))  # AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

I would argue that `Bar` is a perfectly valid (albeit not very useful) example of a subscriptable class. An instance even passes the `iter()` check! Yet should it be considered an iterable? Both the documentation and common sense say no.

---

### Conclusion

Determining whether or not something is *"iterable"* comes down to what you mean by the term. And I would argue that (if anything) the documentation suggesting that the `iter()` is reliable in this regard is misleading. The simple subclass check with the ABC `Iterable` is not sufficient, if you consider the sequence protocol to also be a reasonable version of an iterable.

IMHO, the only *actually* reliable way of determining if an object is iterable is to chain a `next()` call with an `iter()` call, which in practice amounts to a plain `for`-loop. If that raises an error, the object is not iterable.

Final example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class RealIter:
    def __iter__(self) -> RealIter:
        print(f"called {self.__class__.__name__}.__iter__")
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> str:
        print(f"called {self.__class__.__name__}.__next__")
        return "Hi, mom!"

class SeqIter:
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> str:
        print(f"called {self.__class__.__name__}.__getitem__({key})")
        return "Hi, mom!"

for item in RealIter():
    print(item)
    break

for item in SeqIter():
    print(item)
    break
```

Output:

```
called RealIter.__iter__
called RealIter.__next__
Hi, mom!
called SeqIter.__getitem__(0)
Hi, mom!
```

---

### Related

[How to check a class/type is iterable (uninstantiated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568964)

Comment: I think I was very confused with a lot of things about this issue and I didn’t realized that I asked for runtime check when, in my mind, I meant static type check. You did a great answer to a question I didn’t had, but I realize now how interesting it was. Thanks for it. I will keep my question unchanged and will post a new one later about static type check. Great answer !